# i want to display files stored in sdcard on clicking button in my android app. How do i do that?

Tags: android, sd-card

i want to display files stored in sdcard on clicking button in my android app. How do i do that?
I search a lot for browsing sdcard for files which i can choose for attachment in my android Tab app.

Comment: Actually in my app..there is button which onclickicking should act similar to what happens when we click on attach file in gmail.On clicking but i should be able to brows files on sd card and select it as attachment. please help

Comment: any type....image or pdf or doc etc

Comment: what is your actual req.? you just attach file in your app then what should be do ? that will be mail of save in app dir ?

Comment: on click of Add attachment button, i want to open file browser so that i can select for attachment....

Comment: that concept get it. but i want to know on letter what you will to do with that file ? just think that i browse that file add attach what will you do next.

Comment: after attaching file may be i upload it to server....but can you help me to browse and select file from sd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a open source project which gives you a complete file picker and can be invoked using intents

https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser

Comment: i cant use extenal libraries. above link asks to add that library to project

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/) link. its File Chooser example in that you will get current Directory.

Now you have do that like on touch of list item you have to get that doc path and that will useful to send to server or ant other purpose. Make sure if you delete that file from sd card then it will not work .